# Write multiple dataframes to same json object

Tags: r

Using jsonlite package I am able to write a dataframe to json e.g.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% toJSON() %>% write('data/mtcars.json')
diamonds %>% toJSON() %>% write('data/diamonds.json')
```

My question is, is it possible to add both mtcars and diamonds to the same json object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: put the datasets in a list before serializing to JSON:

```r
library(jsonlite)

datasets <- list(datasets = list(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris))
write(toJSON(datasets), "datasets.json")
```

This will result in a JSON file with a structure like:

```json
{
  "datasets": {
    "mtcars": [...],
    "iris": [...]
  }
}
```